# setting max date and min date in html 3months max

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

`<input type='date' class="form-control" id ="datepicker11" />`

```
 <script> $('#datepicker11').datepicker({   maxDate: '+3m',   minDate: '+1d' })  </script>
```

I just want to set the min day to a day from current date and max to 3 months from current day.

Comment: Bootstrap DateTimePicker 3 has a functionality to select dates between a specific range (I mean, 2 calendars synchronized). Of course, you'd have to incorporate Bootstrap to your project, I don't know if that's an option for you, but it's a very good component, easy to setup. Here's a link for it's documentation: [Datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Comment: You code should work as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
$(function() {

    $( "#datepicker11" ).datepicker({ 
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: '+1D',
        maxDate: '+3M',
    });
});
```

here is working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kGjdL/2348/)

Comment: as he said "min day to a day from current date" so it should be `1`